# Proof that $(5m+1)(5m+2)(5m+3)(5m+4)$ is always divisible by $8$ for all natural numbers $m$

Tags: induction, divisibility

My first instincts were to try to prove this by induction. But on applying induction I just get another similar term with just different numbers added to each of the $5m$'s.

Comment: Two of the factors are even, and one of them is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: if you take four consecutive numbers, one of them is divisible by four and one is divisible by two

Comment: The binomial coefficient $\binom n 4$ can be shown to be an integer in various ways. This shows that the product of four consecutive integers is divisible by $4!=24$. You can't do better because $1\times 2\times 3\times 4=24$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the product of any $n$ consecutive natural numbers is divisible by $n!$. So, more is true here. The product is always divisible by $4!=24$. Hence, also divisible by $8$. To prove that product of any $n$ consecutive natural numbers is divisible by $n!$, use the fact that $\binom{a}{b}$ is an integer if $a \geq b \in \mathbb{N}$, or simply use induction.